# In the Windows system using PHP chmod function, such as chmod ('test.php', 0755); 'chmod' function will take effect?

Tags: php, linux

In the Windows system using PHP chmod function, such as chmod ('test.php', 0755); 'chmod' function will take effect? Not just chmod function, as well as chown, chgrp function in the window platform will take effect? Thank you

Comment: May i ask why are you asking this question? Do you have trouble making directorys or deleting files. AFAIK most windows systems use NTFS filesystem which has different permission bits than most unix systems. So i think these commands only works on linux servers.

Comment: In other words PHP chmod, chown, chgrp these functions can only be effective in Linux?

Comment: I think so, in Windows setting file permissions works differently. CHMOD CHGRP, CHOWN are used only in Unix alike environments. I have tried to find a good answer from PHP's documentation but could not find it.